# PIVOT implementation in TD

Tags: pivot, teradata

I want to pivot my data and i am aware that we have Pivot function in teradata 16.
I am not sure how to use it. I am aware of other methods like max(case...) but my data set is large so i can't use that.

Can anyone tell me how to use pivot here:

```
SERV_PROVIDER_ID    CALL_START_DT   cnt1    
50003                  4/15/2018    25,117  
50003                  4/16/2018    65,630  
50003                  4/17/2018    63,880  
50003                  4/18/2018    40,080
```

Want data like

```
SERV_PRIDER_ID  CALL_START_DT1 CNT1 CALL_START_DT2  CNT2 CALL_START_DT3 CNT3
```

I am only looking for 4 days data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are those 4 days know in advance? Btw, MAX(CASE) will not be slower than PIVOT :-)

Comment: Yes, those are for 4 days ..

Comment: Then simply use MAX(CASE)

Comment: Just curious how to use Pivot function here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When those four dates are known:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytab
PIVOT
 ( Sum(cnt1) 
   FOR CALL_START_DT
    IN (DATE'2018-04-15'
       ,DATE'2018-04-16'
       ,DATE'2018-04-17'
       ,DATE'2018-04-18'
       )
 ) AS dt;
```

But your expected result looks like you want those days dynamically:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT t.*,
      Row_Number()
      Over (PARTITION BY SERV_PROVIDER_ID
            ORDER BY CALL_START_DT) AS rn
   FROM mytab AS t
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
PIVOT
 ( Min(CALL_START_DT) AS CALL_START_DT,
   Sum(cnt1) AS Cnt
   FOR rn
    IN (1 
       ,2
       ,3
       ,4
       )
 ) AS dt;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dnoeth!!
When u are around there is never a question which gets unanswered.!!

Comment: Hallo, I used the syntax from the top code while pivoting. I am extracting Kalenderwoche, according to my problem. Instead of `IN (15,16,17,18)` I extract these 4 KWs from a table containing all these 4 KW values like `IN (select x from DB.KW_Tabelle)`, but it doesn't work. Normally, this syntax `IN (select x from DB.KW_Tabelle)` works in normal SQL query I use on TERADATA, but while Pivoting TERADATA doesn't react, no errors. Your perspektiv will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @cph_sto: Hard to tell without details. Try to create the base data with the subquery on KW in a CTE first.

Comment: Does the "for" mean that It is using a for loop? Trying to follow this example, I know this was a very long time ago but could be very similar to what I have to solve right now

Comment: @user18139 This is not a FOR in a Stored Procedure, here FOR simply references the column used to pivot.