# Teradata Convert Rows to Columns (PIVOT)

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table like

[image: Table1 Image]

and

i want that table to be converted to

[image: Table2 Image]

Using **TeraData** Query

Comment: hey 
For **TeraData** follow this if it helps 

https://forgetcode.com/teradata/1294-converting-columns-into-rows


please check link SQL Server 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917409/2527905

Answer (score 1):

If you know the list of values, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when name = 'AA' then value end) as aa,
       max(case when name = 'BB' then value end) as bb,
       max(case when name = 'CC' then value end) as cc,
       . . .
from t;
```

If you don't know the list of values, then you cannot do this with a simple SQL query.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it works when column names are static but in my case Column names and their values changes dynamically so instead of hard coding the case is it possible to make it work for dynamically generated table?

Comment: Dynamically generated SQL is allowed only in stored procedures. You can compile any query as string and than execute it.