# Teradata: IN clause in Pivot can't take data from Table

Tags: sql, teradata

I wish to extract a few `Calender Weeks` from an yearly data. Once that's done, I want to pivot it, so that there is one row for each `ID`.

We have a table `DB.MY_CWs` having just one column `CW` containing the `Calender Weeks` we are interested in.

The following code extracts the relevant `Calender Weeks`.

```
CREATE TABLE DB.MY_TABLE  AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    WeekNumber_Of_Year(Sales_Date)) AS CW,
    AVG(Sales) AS Sales
    FROM DB.DataBase_XYZ
    WHERE CW IN (SELECT CW FROM DB.MY_CWs)
    GROUP BY ID,CW
) WITH DATA;
```

This Code gives us the output like this:

[image: Initial Output]

But, I would like to pivot it so that I get an output like this:

[image: Desired Output]

I took the help from code [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917409/pivot-implementation-in-td/) and ran the following, but `TeraData` doesn't respond and there is no Error either.

```
CREATE TABLE DB.MY_TABLE2  AS
(
SELECT *
FROM DB.MY_TABLE
PIVOT
 (SUM(Sales) AS  Sales
  FOR CW IN (SELECT CW FROM DB.MY_CWs)
 ) AS dt 
) WITH DATA;
```

If instead of `(SELECT CW FROM DB.MY_CWs)` I would have used `(15,16,17)`, then everything works fine and I would have got the pivoted Table, as shown above.

Can anyone suggest where I am making the mistake?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate the scenario.
I am getting below error.

```
CREATE TABLE Failed. 4306: (-4306)Invalid PIVOT query: PIVOT query with sub-query in IN-List is not supported in DDL statement.
```

There are few limitation while using subquery in pivot table.

TD Documentation:
https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-NewSQL-Engine-Release-Summary/March-2019/Release-16.20-Feature-Update-1-Features/Subquery-Support-in-PIVOT-IN-List

**Snippet from TD Documentation**

> **Considerations**
>
> PIVOT with a subquery in the IN-list is not supported in a multistatement request. PIVOT columns are decided dynamically at the optimization phase. Because of this dynamic behavior, the following are usage considerations of a PIVOT query with a subquery in the IN-list.
>
> - ***Not supported in DDL creation statements.***
> - Not supported in stored  procedure's cursor FETCH statement.
> - SET operations are not allowed on a PIVOT query if subquery is given in the IN-list.
> - Resultant PIVOT column names cannot be explicitly    specified in the SELECT list.
> - Does not support ORDER BY clause.

If you are using SQL Assistant, kindly check your history for the error details.
Otherwise you can query dbc.dbqlogtbl to check the errortext.

### Workaround:

You can achieve the desired output through Dynamic SQL and Stored Procedure.

Steps:

1. Convert the output of the subquery to a String. We can do that through XMLAGG.
2. Concatenate the Step1 output in the IN Clause and execute the dynamically generated SQL.

```sql
REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_PIVOT()
BEGIN
DECLARE Sqltxt VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE CWtxt VARCHAR(250);

--Convert rows from MY_CWs to comma delimited string
SET CWtxt=(SELECT TRIM(  TRAILING ',' FROM  (  XMLAGG(CAST(CW AS VARCHAR(10))||',') (VARCHAR(255)) )  ) FROM MY_CWs);
SET Sqltxt=('CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE2  AS
(
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
PIVOT
 (SUM(Sales) AS  Sales
  FOR CW IN ('|| CWtxt  ||')
 ) AS dt 
) WITH DATA;') ;

CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL(Sqltxt);

END;


CALL  DYNAMIC_PIVOT();
```

Comment: Thank you Abinash. I will look into it. Best wishes.

Comment: You can achieve your desired output through dynamic SQL. See if it helps!

Comment: Wow, I was also thinking something like this where I could concatenate the string and then run it as SQL statement. Let me try. I will let you know. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tried the code, but I get the Error `STATEMENT 1: REPLACE  failed.  Failed [2644 : HY000] No more room in database U_PRD` ... Secondly, there is one thing that I don't understand - regarding the `TRIM` statement, why `FROM MY_CWs` is in the last part of `SET` statement? How does SQL know that `CW` comes from `MY_CWs`. I don't understand the syntax. Can you kindly shed some light on that Abinash? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM  (XMLAGG(CAST(CW AS VARCHAR(10))||',') (VARCHAR(255)))) ||') FROM MY_CWs` . This will convert the rows of MY_Cws into a comma delimited string. No more room in database error is either due to no `permanent space ` is assigned to U_PRD or it is out of permanent space. Ask your DBA to add perm space to U_PRD. Alternatively create the procedure in DB which you have access to create the table. Edited the code for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much Abinash for your prompt help. It's very much appreciated. I could finally sort the issue.