# Teradata: On doing PIVOT operation values of columns interchange

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having a `Table` (`DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED`) on `TeraData` having millions of rows, and 4 `columns` - `ID`, `Week`, `Sales` & `Profits`. Here below is a small microcosm of the problem.

For sake of illustration `DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED` is like this:

[image: Unpivoted Table]

I want to `PIVOT` this table. Following is my code:

```
SET SQL_STMT = ('CREATE TABLE DB.TAB_PIVOTED AS
                (   SELECT * FROM DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED
                    PIVOT
                    (   SUM(Sales) AS  Sales, SUM(Profits) AS Profits  
                        FOR KW_Prefix IN (
                                          'CW_1' AS CW_1,
                                          'CW_2' AS CW_2,
                                          'CW_3' AS CW_3
                                         )
                    ) AS dt 
               ) WITH DATA;'
              ) ;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;
```

The strange thing is that, on `PIVOTING`, everytime I get a different table `DB.TAB_PIVOTED`, where values across different columns are interchanged. For eg; one time the output can be:

[image: Pivoted Table]

But, next time, it could be a dfferent result, with values interchanged, though `Profits` & `Sales` maintain their pairing. In one output they could be under `CW_1`, where as on another run, it could be under `CW_3`:

[image: Pivoted Table 2]

This problem may not be reproduced on small data, but with my data in millions and `CW` varing from 1 to 52, I see it all the time.

Does anyone have an idea, where in the `pivoting` am I making the mistake?

Inputs would be very esteemed.

Update:

I tried running the code directly as well, instead of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT`,but same strange results.

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TAB_PIVOTED AS
                    (   SELECT * FROM DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED
                        PIVOT
                        (   SUM(Sales) AS  Sales, SUM(Profits) AS Profits  
                            FOR KW_Prefix IN (
                                              'CW_1' AS CW_1,
                                              'CW_2' AS CW_2,
                                              'CW_3' AS CW_3
                                             )
                        ) AS dt 
                   ) WITH DATA;
```

Comment: I can see how left-to-right order of the labels might not match the order in the IN list, but the values in columns with the same label ought to be the same. Report it as a bug and code the conditional aggregations yourself, e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN KW_Prefix = 'CW_1' THEN Sales END) AS CW_1_Sales, ...`

Comment: @cph_sto , with reference to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229510/teradata-in-clause-in-pivot-cant-take-data-from-table), if you are generating the `IN` clause through XMLAGG, I am suspecting the issue might be due to the XMLAGG output, which is not in ordered manner by default. Are you facing the issue even while having static `IN` clause?

Comment: @Abinash Well, unfortunately I did not try the static IN clause. That’s an interesting vista you have mentioned. I will try it on Monday and let you know. Many many thanks.

Comment: @Fred Well, that’s the thing. The column values inter change. Had it been that column order is getting shuffled, I would have taken that into my stride. But, now I am literally getting garbage output where even values get placed under wrong column heads. I am actually creating time series of Calendar Weeks, so such a result ruins everything.

Comment: @Abinash I used static `IN` clause, with hard coding `'CW_1' AS CW_1,                      'CW_2' AS CW_2,.....`, but the results were still stange, with the values under columns interchanged. This is very very unusual.

Comment: @cph_sto, its very unusual, while comparing I believe you are making sure the order of `ID` column. Can you execute a `MINUS` between the same query multiple times and see if it returns any result.    `SELECT * FROM DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED
PIVOT
(   SUM(Sales) AS  Sales, SUM(Profits) AS Profits  
 FOR KW_Prefix IN ('CW_1' AS CW_1,'CW_2' AS CW_2,'CW_3' AS CW_3)
) AS dt 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM DB.TAB_UNPIVOTED
PIVOT
(   SUM(Sales) AS  Sales, SUM(Profits) AS Profits  
 FOR KW_Prefix IN ('CW_1' AS CW_1,'CW_2' AS CW_2,'CW_3' AS CW_3)
) AS dt 
`

Comment: @Abinash After doing some investigation, may be I know why this strange behavior is occuring. I found out that main `DB` is getting updated every few minutes and I am appending this new data to the old pivoted table, something like this: `INSERT INTO DB.TAB_PIVOTED SELECT * FROM DBX_DWH_SBX_GB23_PRD.TAB_DELTA;` Now, the column order in `TAB_DELTA` is different from `TAB_PIVOTED`, so wrong values come under wrong columns. One way could be to have column_names sorted alphabetically, so that order of columns can't change. So, in Q posted previously, I have to ensure that column names are sorted.

Comment: Great, You can directly Order it using the `XMLAGG`. `SELECT TRIM(  TRAILING ',' FROM  (  XMLAGG(CAST(CW AS VARCHAR(10))||',' ORDER BY CW ASC)  (VARCHAR(255)) )  ) FROM MY_CWs`.

Comment: @Abinash Hi Abinash. Many thanks for the snippet. Now, after having columns placed alphabetically, I don't have this problem of values interchnging. THANK YOU so much for your kind help. Kindly, accept some upvotes.

Comment: Also Instead of `INSERT INTO DB.TAB_PIVOTED SELECT * FROM ` use exact column names. So that even if you mess-up the order, it wont affect. Something like `INSERT INTO DB.TAB_PIVOTED SELECT ID,CW1_SALES,CW2_SALES... FROM DBX_DWH_SBX_GB23_PRD.TAB_DELTA `.

Comment: @Abinash I did that to be sure that the order doesn't change Thanks a lot.